# How to concat strings in different row on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

Let's say I have a table `Foo` and has a column `name`. I want to concatenate all names in `Foo`. For example

Table Foo

```
  Name
---------
  name1
  name2
  name3
```

I want to write a query that returns `name1name2name3` or if possible `name1,name2,name3`.

I have done some googling and see `concat` function but it only concats columns of same row. I couldn't find a function or a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use string_agg

```
SELECT string_agg(Foo, ', ') AS col
FROM   tbl
```